# Necessary steps for using a gem (e.g. json) in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm having trouble getting rubygems to work in my Rails app.  Specifically, I'm trying to use the json gem, documented here: http://flori.github.com/json/  I can successfully use JSON.parse() in IRB and script/console but not in my rails app.

I know it's some combination of config.gem 'json' in environment.rb and other things, but can't find a good explanation anywhere.

Can someone give me a concise list of what is required to use this gem OR point me towards comprehensive documentation of using gems in Rails?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.gem is used for gem dependency in rails and it does nothing more than telling rails that a gem is needed, and helping the user install the appropriate gem, etc (more details here: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/4/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-gem-dependencies)

however by installing a gem, it should be able to be used by the rails app automatically, if not, probably you can add `require "json"` into `environment.rb` or in an `.rb` files in the `initializers` folder?

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  There's decent documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Configuration/gem

Once you have used config.gem in environment.rb, you should not need to 'require' it later.

My problem was that I had not stopped and restarted the server!  It worked in script/console because everything was getting reloaded every time.